# How to add user control in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

I have created a user control outside Sitecore CMS now I would like to import it in Sitecore. Any one knows that method.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You could do that in the Core database. Have a read through [this article](http://sitecorehelp.com/blog/6/Creating-custom-applications-in-Sitecore).

What it tells you is:

> Log into Sitecore and choose the Core database. 
> Add a new application
>   underneath Sitecore > Content > Application 
> In the newly created
>   element find the datasection and fill out the path to the application
>   in the "Application" inputfield. This could eg. be
>   \MyCompanyName\Administration\Default.aspx. 
> Choose a display name and
>   a icon for the application. 
> Next go to Sitecore -> Content -> Documents
>   & Settings -> All Users (if all users needs access to it) -> Start menu ->
>   Left and add your new shortcut.

If you have created a XAML application, you can find more information [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/XML%20Sheer%20UI/My%20first%20XML%20application.aspx).

Comment: Trayek, Thanks a lot :). Hope this will help us.